# Access VBA generated ODBC connection string reverts

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, connection-string

I am creating a local MS Access (365) front end application for a SQL Server (Express 2019) DB which is located on a local shared server.

I have a login form that relinks all of the linked tables and views when a user logs in. (This is not primarily for security, so please don't tell me how inadequate this set up is for security - I know.)

Basically, I have a local table in the Access application that lists all the table names that need relinking at login. At login, the current links are deleted, then the code loops through the list of tables and links them according to a connection string that is built in the process, including the UID and the PWD.  But when I check on the connection string after login, it doesn't include the login info. My Excel workbook that has a data connection to one of these linked tables cannot connect until I manually edit the string in the Linked Table Manager.

Below is the code for the login process:

```
Private Sub cmdConnect_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim rst1 As Recordset
Dim strServer As String
Dim strDB As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim strConnect As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strPass As String
Dim strPrimary As String

On Error GoTo HandleErr
Set db = CurrentDb
strPass = DLookup("[Password]", "tblUsers", "[User] = '" & Me.txtUser & "'")
If StrComp(Me.txtPwd, strPass, vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
strMsg = "Incorrect Username or password!"
GoTo ExitHere
End If


' Create a recordset to obtain server object names.
    
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblSQLTables", dbOpenSnapshot)
    If rst.EOF Then
        strMsg = "There are no tables listed in tblSQLTables."
        GoTo ExitHere
    End If
'Assign the current user in table
Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset("tblUsers", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
With rst1
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until rst1.EOF
        .Edit
    Select Case !user
        Case Me.txtUser
            !Current = -1
            
        Case Else
            !Current = 0
            
    End Select
    .Update
    .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

strConnect = "ODBC;Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Trusted_Connection=No;DSN=SQL1;UID=" _
            & Me.txtUser & ";PWD=" & Me.txtPwd & ";"

'delete all existing linked tables
Call deleteLinks


 ' Walk through the recordset and create the links.
    Do Until rst.EOF
        strServer = rst!SQLServer
        strDB = rst!SQLDatabase
        strTable = rst!SQLTable
        ' Create a new TableDef object.
        Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef("dbo_" & strTable, 0, "dbo." & strTable, strConnect & "Server=" & strServer & ";Database=" & strDB & ";")
        
        ' Set the Connect property to establish the link.
        
        db.TableDefs.Append tdf
        Debug.Print tdf.Connect
        Set tdf = Nothing
       
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

strMsg = "Tables linked successfully."
    
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
  DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.name
  DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStart"
ExitHere:
    MsgBox strMsg, , "Link SQL Tables"
    Exit Sub
HandleErr:
    Select Case Err
        Case Else
            strMsg = Err & ": " & Err.Description
            Resume ExitHere
    End Select


End Sub

Private Sub deleteLinks()
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If tdf.name Like "dbo_*" Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tdf.name
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

When I look at the immediate window to see the printed tdf.connect it gives me:

```
ODBC;DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=RNC1SQL\SQLEXPRESS;UID=****;PWD=*************;Trusted_Connection=No;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=RNCMasterfile;
```

But when I look at the connection string in the Linked Table Manager, I get the following:

```
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=RNC1SQL\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=No;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=RNCMasterfile;
```

The odd thing is I can access and use the tables in Access, but I have Excel spreadsheets with connections to Access queries based on the linked tables and they don't work if the connection string doesn't contain the login info.

Any ideas to programmatically force the connection string to contain this info?

Comment: Why are you setting `strConnect` with a DSN (`DSN=SQL1`) when you later on set the server and the database explicitly? Maybe this mixing causes the trouble? Try without the DSN.

Comment: Oh that was something I had tried and it didn't change anything. Forgot to take it back out.  I'm very green at this...

Answer (score 0):

Try linking your tables using `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` instead.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", [your_cnn_string], acTable, [source_tbl_name], [linked_table_name], , True
```

The last option in `TranserDatabase` is `StoreLogin`.

I use this in my own apps.

Read about `TransferDatabase` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.DoCmd.TransferDatabase).

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: Great! That seemed to work. Buuuut. Now it wants to ask me about primary keys for all the Views that I am linking to as tables.  Many of these views are complicated queries with no primary key. How do I bypass having to assign a primary key when the transfer comes in? Right now I have to hit cancel 20 times.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember that. It's been a while, but I believe if you go through and assign the PKs the first time Access remembers your responses. I no longer get prompted and I've checked my code for PK assignment--nothing. As for ones without a PK, I believe you select OK (or whatever the option) without selecting a PK.